# Downloading visual studio 2017 community with Invoke-WebRequest pulls broken .exe

Tags: powershell

I'm not really sure what's happening to be honest. I'm trying to download a series of files and the only one that's not coming out right is Visual Studio 2017

```
$vs_url = "https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15#"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $vs_url -OutFile C:\pulled-files\vs_community.exe -UserAgent [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::FireFox
```

When I run this script it downloads the file without any errors. However, when I run the .exe a large orange banner popups telling me that I need to find the correct version for my system. If I use the same link manually it works fine. The file name is different, though I've used both what I have here and the file name when downloaded manually but it makes no difference. The .exe wont run.

Can anyone explain why this is occurring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visual studio url you are using references the download page, not the file itself. If you open the exe file in notepad it will likely display html code instead of the standard non-readable contents of a working exe file. You must find the true file path in the server. I looked into the code and I found that the true URL of the exe is https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/11835057/045b56eb413191d03850ecc425172a7d/vs_Community.exe.

Although I am sure that is a temporary URL and will be disposed after a while. In conclusion, if it indeed is a temporary URL, then there is no way to download it directly from the server without reuploading. I suggest at least trying the URL above though.

Comment: Ha, I didn't even think of that! Thanks mate, if it's only temporary I'll figure something else out or just cut it form the script entirely but for now the link you supplied works. Thanks again.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer so I get the reputation please :D

Comment: Hehe my apologies I had to wait for the minimum timer and so I ran to the store, accepting now!